# Bigcommerce Stencil Recently Viewed Items

Tags: bigcommerce

I am trying to display recently viewed items in a Stencil theme, but am not able to get the data on the page. I am calling the following Front Matter attribute marked as global (available on all pages) here.

**Stencil Docs example**

recently_viewed:    null    Boolean indicating whether to display recently viewed products. No filtering available.

https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/front-matter-variables

```
recently_viewed: true
```

When I inspect the JSON on the page by appending '/?debug=context' to my URL, there is no data containing recently viewed items.

Has anyone else successfully displayed recently viewed items on a page in stencil?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is currently only working for logged in customers. If you are seeing this behave abnormally from that, please let us know. It does not have feature parity with Blueprint themes' sideproductrecentlyviewed.

Comment: will this be updated soon? Recently viewed items for all users (not just logged in) is a pretty common need for ecommerce stores. As well as "customers also bought" on the product page. Any idea when this will be implemented?